# Perl SYSTEM command fails with "Bad file descriptor" when running via Jenkins

Tags: perl, jenkins

I have a simple system command to copy file from one folder to another:

`my $cmd = "xcopy /Y c:\DBs\Support\db.bak c:\jenkins\workdir\sql-bak-files";`

When I try to run the following system commands, all fails:

`1. my $res = qx/$cmd/;
 2. my $res = qx($cmd);
 3. using back ticks`

All tries returned the error: `Error number -1, error message: "Bad file descriptor"`.

When trying to use system($cmd) the error was `Error number 65280, error message: "No such file or directory"`.

This perl code is running via Jenkins (ver 2.190.1) and perl v5.26.0.
This problem started after migrating the code from mercurial to git, but I don't think it's related.
It worked before, but now always fail :(

Comment: Re "*Error number 65280, error message: "No such file or directory"*", `$!` ("No such file or directory") is meaningless when the error isn't `-1`. 65280 (0xFF00) means the child ran, but returned exit code 255 (0xFF)

Comment: And if I have variables inside the cmd?
    "xcopy /Y \"$text_file\" $text_local_shared_path" ?

Answer (score 3):

A backslash has a special meaning in a Perl quoted string. It is used to escape the following character - to "turn off" any special meaning. If you want to use a backslash in a Perl quoted string, then you need to use another backslash to escape it.

```
my $cmd = 'xcopy /Y c:\\DBs\\Support\\db.bak c:\\jenkins\\workdir\\sql-bak-files';
```

Alternatively, Perl recognises forward slashes in Windows paths, so it might be easier to replace your code with this:

```
my $cmd = 'xcopy /Y c:/DBs/Support/db.bak c:/jenkins/workdir/sql-bak-files';
```

Note that in both cases I have replaced your double-quotes with single-quotes. This has no effect on your problem, but it seems strange to use double-quoted strings if you're not using any of their special characteristics (like the expansion of variables).

**Update:** To debug a problem like this, you can try `print`ing the string.

```
$ perl -E'say "xcopy /Y c:\DBs\Support\db.bak c:\jenkins\workdir\sql-bak-files"'
xcopy /Y c:DBsSupportdb.bak c:jenkinsworkdirsql-bak-files
```

Comment: Re "*Perl recognises forward slashes in Windows paths*", Not really. Perl doesn't know anything about paths. It's Windows itself that recognizes forward slashes as a valid path separator. That said, many Windows commands require paths using `/` as a separator to be quoted since `/` normally denotes the start of a command line option. Unfortunately, that trick doesn't work with `xcopy`. It simply doesn't accept `/` as a path separator.

Comment: And if I have variables inside the cmd?
    "xcopy /Y \"$text_file\" $text_local_shared_path" ?

Comment: @ShaiAlon: Or use `qq[...]` instead of `"..."` to simplify things.